# Android Database Issue: Not able to create table in the Same Database

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing an issue, and not able to resolve. I have searched and tried everything, but still, I am unable to fix this.

I have created two separate classes, and both use same database `DGWallet.db` The first class is `DatabaseHelper.java`

```
package com.example.dell.sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import com.example.dell.model.User;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

   // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DGWallet.db";

    // User table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "users";

    // User Table Columns names

    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE = "date";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone_no";

    // create table sql query
    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_PHONE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE  + " DATE, "
            + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }


    /**
     * This method is to create user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void addUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, user.getPhone());
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE, user.getBirthDate());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method is to fetch all user and return the list of user records
     *
     * @return list
     */
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_PHONE,
                COLUMN_NAME,
                COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE,
                COLUMN_EMAIL,
                COLUMN_PASSWORD
        };
        // sorting orders
        String sortOrder =
                COLUMN_NAME + " ASC";
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // query the user table
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id,user_name,user_email,user_password FROM user ORDER BY user_name;
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,    //columns to return
                null,        //columns for the WHERE clause
                null,        //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,       //group the rows
                null,       //filter by row groups
                sortOrder); //The sort order


        // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                User user = new User();
                user.setPhone(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PHONE))));
                user.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
                user.setBirthDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE)));
                user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EMAIL)));
                user.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD)));
                // Adding user record to list
                userList.add(user);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // return user list
        return userList;
    }

    /**
     * This method to check user exist or not
     *
     * @param email
     * @return true/false
     */
    public boolean checkUser(String email) {

        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_NAME
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_EMAIL + " = ?";

        // selection argument
        String[] selectionArgs = {email};

        // query user table with condition
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com';
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                      //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This method to check user exist or not
     *
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * @return true/false
     */
    public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {

        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_NAME
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " = ?";

        // selection arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};

        // query user table with conditions
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com' AND user_password = 'qwerty';
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                       //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


}
```

From this class, the table is getting created, which I have checked from the adb shell:

```
sqlite3 DG                                                                     <
DGWallet.db         DGWallet.db-shm     DGWallet.db-wal
qlite3 DGWallet.db                                                            <
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .table
android_metadata  users           
sqlite> select * from users;
```

However, when I use similar type of code, to create another table, I get an error message. Also, the table creating code is not getting executed. I have checked this by removing comma, and still, it did not throw any error.

```
package com.example.dell.sql;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import com.example.dell.model.Add_User;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class DatabasePersonDetails extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DGWallet.db";

        private static final String TABLE_USERS = "persondetails";


        public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "firstname";
        public static final String COLUMN_MIDDLE_NAME = "middlename";
        public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "lastname";
        public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
        public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
        public static final String COLUMN_CREDIT_BALANCE = "credit_balance";
        public static final String COLUMN_DEBIT_BALANCE = "debit_balace";

        private static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + DatabasePersonDetails.TABLE_USERS + " (" +
                        COLUMN_PHONE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_MIDDLE_NAME + " TEXT," +
                        COLUMN_LAST_NAME + "Text," +
                        COLUMN_ADDRESS + "Text," +
                        COLUMN_CREDIT_BALANCE + "Real," +
                        COLUMN_DEBIT_BALANCE + "Real" + ")";

        public DatabasePersonDetails(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
            // to simply to discard the data and start over
            db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void add_user(Add_User add_user){


            // Gets the data repository in write mode
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, add_user.getPhone());
            values.put(COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, add_user.getFirstname());
            values.put(COLUMN_MIDDLE_NAME,add_user.getMiddlename());
            values.put(COLUMN_LAST_NAME,add_user.getLastname());
            values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS,add_user.getAddress());
            values.put(COLUMN_CREDIT_BALANCE,add_user.getCredit_bal());
            values.put(COLUMN_DEBIT_BALANCE,add_user.getDebit_bal());

            db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null,values);
            db.close();

        }

        public List<Add_User> getAllUsers(){
            String [] columns = {
                    COLUMN_PHONE,
                    COLUMN_FIRST_NAME,
                    COLUMN_MIDDLE_NAME,
                    COLUMN_LAST_NAME,
                    COLUMN_ADDRESS,
                    COLUMN_CREDIT_BALANCE,
                    COLUMN_DEBIT_BALANCE
            };

            String sortOrder = COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + "ASC";

            List<Add_User> add_userList=new ArrayList<Add_User>();

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, //Table to query
                    columns,    //columns to return
                    null,        //columns for the WHERE clause
                    null,        //The values for the WHERE clause
                    null,       //group the rows
                    null,       //filter by row groups
                    sortOrder); //The sort order

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Add_User addUser = new Add_User();
                    addUser.setPhone(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PHONE))));
                    addUser.setFirstname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIRST_NAME)));
                    addUser.setMiddlename(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MIDDLE_NAME)));
                    addUser.setLastname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LAST_NAME)));
                    addUser.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ADDRESS)));
                    addUser.setCredit_bal(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CREDIT_BALANCE))));
                    addUser.setDebit_bal(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DEBIT_BALANCE))));
                    ;
                    // Adding user record to list
                    add_userList.add(addUser);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            // return user list
            return add_userList;

        }

   }
```

I tried changing version number from 3 to 4, and I also checked the version number, which emulator has.

```
3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57 0c55d179733b46d8d0ba4d88e01a25e10677046ee3da1d5b1581e86726f2alt2
```

**I removed the app from the emulator, cleaned the project, and checked again, but still the issue persists.**

This is the error message:

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting firstname=null address=xyz debit_balace=5000.0 phone=7022013810 credit_balance=5000.0 middlename=Rao lastname=Lambu
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: persondetails (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO persondetails(firstname,address,debit_balace,phone,credit_balance,middlename,lastname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:901)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:512)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1562)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
                      at com.example.dell.sql.DatabasePersonDetails.add_user(DatabasePersonDetails.java:74)
                      at com.example.dell.digitalwallet.Add_Users.PostDataToSqlite(Add_Users.java:118)
                      at com.example.dell.digitalwallet.Add_Users$1.onClick(Add_Users.java:95)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
                      at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
                      at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25881)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)

Add_User.java

public class Add_User {

    private String firstname;
    private String middlename;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    private long Phone_No;
    private float Credit_bal;
    private float Debit_bal;
    // private String birth_date;

    public String getFirstname() {return firstname;}

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname =firstname;

    }

    public String getMiddlename() {return middlename;}

    public void setMiddlename(String middlename){
        this.middlename=middlename;
    }



    public String getLastname() {return lastname;}

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname=lastname;
    }

    public String getAddress() {return address;}

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address=address;
    }


    public long getPhone() {
        return Phone_No;
    }

    public void setPhone(long Phone_no) {

        this.Phone_No = Phone_no;
    }

    public float getCredit_bal(){return Credit_bal;}

    public void setCredit_bal(float Credit_bal){
        this.Credit_bal=Credit_bal;
    }

    public float getDebit_bal(){return Debit_bal;}

    public void setDebit_bal(float Debit_bal){
        this.Debit_bal=Debit_bal;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Your error message says that table does not exist. Are you sure that table creating code is called before you try to run insert to that table? Sorry, but from these snippets it's not clear when is add_user called. Seems like it's only issue in order of your commands. BTW, why are you not creating whole DB in one place, instead of altering it and adding tables later?

Comment: No,CREATE_USER_TABLE is not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments. Issue is that `DatabasePersonDetails.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` nor 
`DatabasePersonDetails.onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)` is being called before you try to add user to table, thus, table does not exist.

Make sure that you call one of the 2 methods that created the tables, before trying to add data. (Quickest fix).

My suggestion though is to add all table creation in the same place, so that when you create database, you create all the necessary tables in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the Database, instead of using DGWallet.db. This is working.

The reason that why I have kept the design like this is that, these both are for different screens, and is used for storing different information. Debugging would be easier with this design.